# What is the meaning of adding specific dimension to "None+" in tensorflow's placeholder?

Tags: python, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning

In the code below the state dimensions variable --> state_dim is added to (None,). Why do we add that when we already specify the tensor size to be variable?

```
states = tf.placeholder('float32',(None,)+state_dim,name="states")
actions = tf.placeholder('int32',name="action_ids")
cumulative_rewards = tf.placeholder('float32', name="cumulative_returns")
```

Comment: What's `state_dim`?

Comment: state_dim here is the state dimensions for cart pole gym environment. These are 4 float values describing cart position, cart velocity, pole angle, pole velocity at the tip.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the exact context this is fairly hard to answer. But in general in model training applications, the first dimension is a placeholder for the batch size, which is variable typically and only known at runtime. The dimension of the data you are working on is however normally predefined and needs to be coded into the graph to be executed.

So if `state_dim` represents and image with shape `(300, 300, 3)` then the resulting placeholder shape becomes `(None, 300, 300, 3)`

Comment: Sorey for not mentioning the context. Here I am trying to generate a neural network to obtain policy for cartpole environment. The input given to the neural network is states of type float 32, in this case the dimension is 4. State_dim represents the state dimension.